# Bash how to divide two columns an do something with result

Tags: linux, bash

This is the simple txt file, delimiter is space:

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4
1 1500 0 name1
2 25000 43234 name2
3 0 12000 name3
```

How can I divide (col3 / col2), if the ratio is 2 or is 3 (a couple of OR), it should do something like `echo rate for COL4 (name) is less than 10`, else `echo rate is more than 10`.

**Edit1**

This is only a sample output, not necessarily correct:

```
ratio for name1 is less than 10.
ratio for name2 is more than 10.
ratio for name3 is less than 10.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: If you mean numerical floating division, then it can't be done in "bash" directly

Comment: @Cyrus I updated. Also, there are some zeros in the sample but I get cannot divide by zero.

Comment: @UmbQbify then using something like Python?

Comment: `col3 / col2),` How to divide by 0? This looks really simple in awk. Consider https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html `if the ratio is 2 or is 3` ? What if the ratio is 1.72936 like in the second line?

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought a lot, but have no idea for that. I need that too if division is zero.

Comment: What do you need? You have to decide. Did you mean "more than 1", or did you mean is equal to exactly 2 or 3, I do not understand. No ratio is more than 10.

Comment: @KamilCuk if it's zero, then it echos like `Col4 is zero`. I'll process the zeros later, not currently

Comment: in `awk`, another way to guard against divide by zero is straight up doing ::::::::::::::::::::::: `numerator / ( denominator + ! denominator )`

Comment: and if you're checking whether ratio is less than 10, unless you actually need to print out the ratio itself, why not just multiply the denominator by 10 and see if it's larger than numerator and skip the division ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto can you give an example?

Comment: @Saeed :  `echo '25000 43234' | mawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT = OFMT = "%.25g" } { print $0, "\n\t ratio", sprintf("%.11g",ratio = $2/$1), "\n\t is ratio less than 10x ? ", (ratio < 10 ? "yes" : "no"), "\n\t alternative way to check ratio  < 10x  ? ", (+$2 < 10 * $1 ? "yes" : "no") }'` ::::::::::::::::::::::: 
`25000 43234 
  ratio 1.72936 
  is ratio less than 10x ?  yes 
  alternative way to check ratio  < 10x  ?  yes`

Comment: @Saeed : as for the divide by zero guard, it'll be like ::::::::::    ::::  ::::::::::::  `echo 'numerator 43 denominator 0' | gawk -p- '{ print $0, "ratio", ( $2 ) / ( $4 + ! $4 ) }'` ::::::::::: ::::::: `numerator 43 denominator 0 ratio 43`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively simple writing an awk script to do simple transformations.

```
$ awk 'NR!=1{printf "ratio for %s is %s than 10.\n", $4, $2==0?"infinity more":($3/$2>1)?"more":"less"}' <<EOF
Col1 col2 col3 col4
1 1500 0 name1
2 25000 43234 name2
3 0 12000 name3
EOF
ratio for name1 is less than 10.
ratio for name2 is more than 10.
ratio for name3 is infinity more than 10.
```

Awk has been with us for very long time - there are endless tutorials online.